# Div rotation in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation

I'm rotating a div in IE11,

This works:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

But this doesn't:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1 );
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: filters are no longer supported in IE 10+ - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Cheers Adrift. Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: filters are deprecated since IE9 and should not be used.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response Ali but Adrift answered in the comments above.

Comment: Good that you found an answer nonetheless. Welcome

Comment: Go on sure, have the 'accepted answer' anyways!